# ExtJS 5: Chrome, with data-qtip with column selection doesn't work

Tags: extjs, grid, mouseover, qtip

I have added following data-qtip for each column in my grid

```
renderer: function (val, meta, record){
meta.tdAttr = 'data-qtip=" ' + val + '"';
return val;
}
```

The above code adds mouseover to each value in the grid columns. This works fine in FF but in chrome, for the same code, if I use the dropdown menu for any column to hide/show a column, the dropdown menu disappears too fast for the user to make any selection.

Comment: This is a bug in chrome.  I think there is a workaround (I haven't used it) but its happening across EXTJS applications in chrome.  Hopefully fixed soon.

Comment: Take a look at user 'festr' and his override in this topic.  It is for extjs4 but it may work for 5.

https://www.sencha.com/forum/showthread.php?301116

Comment: https://www.sencha.com/forum/announcement.php?f=134&a=58

Comment: I don't seem to able to reproduce this submenu issue with ExtJS 5 + Chrome. Try this fiddle: https://fiddle.sencha.com/#fiddle/o6b

Comment: @GuilhermeLopes the tool tip appears on click but not on hover on Chrome 71. Is this something new or happened earlier as well?

Comment: @SamGhatak I'm running 71.0.3578.98  and still shows up on hover, click has no relation to tooltips at all. If you search for the element with `.ext-quicktips-tip-body` class and setup a break point on `attribute change` you will see that the call that initiates the change is `doTargetOver`.

Comment: Note: There is a `showOnTap` config for ToolTips that if set to `true`, will display the tooltips onClick but only on TouchDevices. Maybe your system was set as touch and something enabled the `showOnTap` flag?? You should investigate.

Comment: I found out something is messed up in chrome in my system, your code runs nice in other machines, Thanks for the quick response though :) @GuilhermeLopes